# How to configure offline map viewer for openstreetmaps on debian?

Tags: conversion, openstreetmap, gis

I've installed Gosmore and was going to download some maps in `osm.bz2` format from [here](http://download.geofabrik.de/).

How can I add them to Gosmore? I was googling but didn't manage to find any solution, so I'm not sure if I will manage to make it work or not.

Maybe there is another good solution for fully legal free offline maps?

**Update**: tried using command

```
 bzcat /file_location/filename.osm.bz2 | gosmore rebuild
```

Got some errors (no any icons found) and then

```
1 while (xmlTextReaderRead (xml) == 1)
```

and nothing happens. Maybe that is so because I installed gosmore from Debian repository, I'll try the way it told in official documentation (though it told that I CAN install from Debian repo).

**Update:** Tried manual installation - the same result. Gave up with gosmore, tried to configure navit, and it doesn't work as well, I see no maps - only rose screen, it seems like maps just not loaded. I found a solution for the same problem on [official maillists](http://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2012/04/msg00308.html), but the solution provided did not work for me.

**Update** I think I found quite good solution, see bellow.

Answer (score 1):

#### OSM formats

According to atleast this github page, titled: [openstreetmap/gosmore](https://github.com/openstreetmap/gosmore), it sounds like it's possible to use Open Street Maps (OSM) with Gosmore. This command is shown with `gosmore`.

```
$ bzcat planet-...osm.bz2 | gosmore rebuild
```

So you should be able to use your `osm.bz2` files like this:

```
$ bzcat osm.bz2 | gosmore rebuild
```

You can also see the above commands in the [README file for Gosmore too](http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/rendering/gosmore/README). Lastly there's a page in the OSM wiki titled: [Gosmore/RebuildGuide](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Gosmore/RebuildGuide), which shows alternative methods to the above depending on the nature of the map data you're attempting to use.

#### PBF formats

If you're looking to import `osm.pbf` files you might be able to find a method on this page in the [OSM wiki on the PBF file format](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PBF_Format).

Additionally there is this tool, `osmconvert`, which looks to be what you want, mainly to convert OSM to PBF. The [wiki page for this command](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert) has pretty good details on its usage.

#### Example

```
$ bzcat europe.osm.bz2 | osmconvert - -o=europe.pbf
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
What about osm.pbf? I read a little, it appears that this format is faster and lighter, so I downloaded asia map in this format to try, but using the command you provided I'm getting only errors. Of corse I'll download bz2 and try as well, just wondering.

Comment: @user63130 - Not sure. I found this page: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Renderers_feature_list. I've never used any of this software and so was only going off the docs. Also this page: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PBF_Format

Comment: @user63130 - see updates.

Comment: Yes, I've already read everything on these links before you provided it, but it was not helpful. And I did not need to convert osm to pbf, I already had pbf, but it seems that gosmore just doesn't work with this format. For me, regretfully, gosmore doesn't work at all. Nither Gosmore nor anything else. But anyway thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found quite good solution - it's called Marble. It stores maps like almost all android map-applications - in images called "tiles". There is a disadvantage: you can not download the whole world map, because it would be too big in size, but the pro is that it works quite fast.

I installed it, it works out of the box, you only have to  select "Openstreetmaps   "theme", go to area you want to be able to access offline, press "File" ->"Download Region",  set  "tile level range" (there is a limitation on tiles number), press  "Ok" and in the right bottom conner of the screen you'll see a loading status.

If you navigate through the map it also caches everything you download, I increased the cache size in "Settings"->"Configure Virtual Globe"->"Cache and Proxy" to 10000. Now I'm downloading maps, it's slow, but I'm sure it's worth it.